# Adding Paint Component To A JPanel

Tags: java, paint, paintcomponent

In my application (using java), a button is pushed and then a panel opens up with a graph on it.  To create the graph I am using graphics/paint.  However, I am unable to get the graphics to show up. For now, I am just trying to paint a circle (instead of the actual graph). It would be much appreciated if someone could explain what I am doing wrong.

```
public class SeeProgressHandleClass extends JPanel{

  public SeeProgressHandleClass(JFrame window) {
    this.window = window;
  }

  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    panel = new JPanel();

    fillPanel();

    window.add(panel);      
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);       
    panel.setBounds(50, 40, 1100, 660);
  }

  public static void fillPanel() {
    Graph graph = new Graph();
    panel.add(graph);
 }
}

public class Graph extends JPanel{

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
  }

}
```

Comment: If the component you're painting manually will not have other components in front of it (Overlapping.), and will also not be transparent (Other components in background.), then you should not do super.paintComponent() because its only purpose would be to waste cycles - given that you have to replace your setBackground call with a g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight()) call anyway. And with these conditions met, you should even override paint() instead of paintComponent() (and again without a super.pain() call) which may increase performance very slightly.

Answer (score 1):

- `Graph` should provide `preferredSize` hints, which will allow the layout manager to make better determinations about how the component should be displayed.  Consider overriding `getPreferredSize`
- Don't call `this.setBackground(Color.white);` inside `paintComponent`, each time you do this, it will trigger a potential repaint request, which will eventually consume all your CPU cycles. Set this in the constructor
- You're adding `Graph` into `JPanel` and then adding this to the screen ... not sure why, but it's making it more confusing
- After `window.add(panel);`, all `window.revalidate()` and `window.repaint()` to trigger a new layout and paint pass